# Calculus Functional Equation

Tags: calculus, functions

Given a function $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$F(x-y) = F(x)F(y), \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}.$$
There are several questions:

> 1. **Prove:** If there is $a \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $F(a) \not = 0$, then $F(0) = 1$.

**My attempts:** Choose $x = 0 =y$, we obtain $F(0) = [F(0)]^2$. So the value of $F(0) = 1$. If $F(0) = 0$, the function $F(x)$ will be identically zero.

> 2. **Determine F(3).**

**My attempts:** Choose $x = 3 = y$. Then
$$F(3-3) = F(3)F(3) \Longrightarrow F(0) = [F(3)]^2 \Longrightarrow F(3) = 1 \vee F(3) = -1.$$

Is it correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it strictly correct to say that ‘a function’ is ‘defined by’ an equation that's satisfied by multiple functions? (For example, both the constant functions 0 and 1.) Wouldn't it be better to say merely that the function _satisfies_ the equation? (Or that the equation defines _a family_ of functions, if we weren't referring to a single function?)

Comment: Your attempt for part 1 does not seem to use $a$ explicitly, and your "identically zero" needs justification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement: If $F(0) = 0$, the function will be identically 0" needs proof.

A better approach would be to consider $F(a-0)$ instead of $F(0-0)$, where $a$ is such that $F(a)\neq0$, since we know such an $a$ exists.

This gives $F(a) = F(a)F(0)$, and you can divide through by $F(a)$.

You can do better for $F(3)$, by considering $F(3 - \frac{3}{2})$.

This gives $F(\frac32)=F(3)F(\frac32)$. You can use your original argument to show $F(\frac32)$ is either $-1$ or $1$. In particular, it's not $0$, so you can divide it out to get $F(3) = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$F(0) = F(x)^2$ for all $x$, and since $F(a)$ is non zero, $F(a-0) = F(a) F(0)$ and so $F(0) = 1$. Hence $F(x)^2 =1$ for all $x$, in particular, $F(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. Since $F({x \over 2}) = F(x-{x \over 2}) = F(x)F({x \over 2})$, we see that $F(x) = 1$ for all $x$.